# How to express "some place for children to play in restaurant or other public"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I found some translations but am not sure if there are better and shorter alternatives:

1. "children playground" — I am thinking about a small place inside, not a large playground;
2. "corner for children" — maybe this is the only one valid.

Is there any other short idiomatic phrase to describe it?

Comment: It has been called a Children's corner in all the places I have been

Comment: I'd call it a *play area*.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it hasn't made it into the dictionaries yet, but [funland](http://www.wordnik.com/words/Funland) is definitely in use. Search "McDonald's Funland" for *many* examples.

Sometimes is spelled as two words "fun land."

Comment: Sounds nice since very simple.

Comment: I've heard it referred to as a "McDonald's Playplace" all my life (in America), but I can't say I've heard "funland". Which it not to say that you are at all wrong, but perhaps "playplace" is another good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

***tot lot***
noun

a small playground for young children ([[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tot%20lot))

Designates special play areas set aside for children, particularly pre-school age children. ([gohistoric](http://gohistoric.com/glossary/tot-lot))

---

[EDIT]
More usage examples, etc.

“Tot lot” is a Parks expression used to describe a space used for the recreational purposes of small children. ([NYCity-Parks](http://www.nycgovparks.org/parks/hotspottotlot/))

In Oklahoma City a number of tot-lots … are incorporated into the development of subdivisions and also you will find plenty of back yards with enough area and play equipment to qualify as a suitable tot-lot. ([imaginativeAmerica](http://www.imaginativeamerica.com/2009/01/classifying-open-space-playgrounds/))

[image]
[A tot-lot in Pigtown, South Baltimore, MD.](http://southbmore.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/458233_10150715428818589_609968588_9733860_1163020034_o.jpg)

Comment: Never heard but very short and nice.